# Find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x + 2\sin(x)}{x+10\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x + 2\sin(x)}{x+10\cos(x)}$.

**Using L'Hospital's Rule:**

since $\frac{d}{dx}(x + 2\sin(x)) = 1 + [0 \cdot \sin(x)] + [2\cdot\cos(x)]=1 +2\cos(x)$

and since  $\frac{d}{dx} (x + 10\cos(x)) = 1 + [0 \cdot \cos(x)] + [10 \cdot -\sin(x)]=1-10\sin(x)$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x + 2\sin(x)}{x+10\cos(x)}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 +2\cos(x)}{1-10\sin(x)}$$

**plug in 0 for x:**

Since $\cos(0) = 1$, and $\sin(0) = 0$

$$=\frac{1 + 2(1)}{1 - 10(0)} = \frac{1+2}{1-0} = 3$$

But this is apparently wrong.

Comment: Can you apply the rule to begin with? Is it a $0/0$ form?

Comment: As long as we are it: *don't use the product rule for functions of the form $af(x)$ with $a$ constant!* $(af)' = af'$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why so complicated? The numerator goes to $0$, and the denominator goes to $10$, so the limit is $0$. Also you cannot use L'Hospital's rule here since the limit is not one of the indeterminate forms that permit the use of L'Hospital.

Comment: @LuminousNutria: This isn't "overthinking"; before you use a rule, you need to make sure you are actually allowed to use it. You didn't check here.